# What are the implications of a warmer earth for hurricanes by 2100?

Tags: weather, climate-science

The main magic number is the surface sea water temperature.  Above, I think 27 C the warm, moist air provides more energy that the storm uses.

This is why the hurricane season is late summer into fall.  This is when the surface water is warmest.  This is today’s image (23 March 2019) showing the current temps of the north Atlantic.  You can see there is a hot spot between south America and Africa.  It’s not big enough for a hurricane, and at the equator, where that hot spot sits, you don’t have Coriolis forces that give spin and structure to a hurricane.

Now take your favourite global warming model for 2100.  Say it’s an increase of 3 C  That means that today’s 24 line becomes 2100’s 27 degree line.  The 24 degree line averages about 20 degrees north latitude. (Using ‘degree’ for temperature and angle can be confusing.  You have been warned…)
So my first kick at the cat based on 3 degrees warmer, would be that possible huricane zone would expand 20 degrees (latitude) further north.

[image: Sea Surface Temps, March 19, 2019]

[image: Tropical Storm Creation zones.]

Notice something else.  Look at the east end of that diagram, and you see where tropical storms start.  A band from 20 degrees north, just off the bulge of Africa, and  moving to 30 degrees north, about at the Florida Georgia border.  So with the 3 degree addition March’s surface temp is the ‘hurricane feeding’ temp.
So not only are storms going to be able to move further north, but we will have a much longer hurricane season.  Indeed, by 2100 hurricanes may be a year round occurrence in the present hurricane belt, with larger and more frequent storms in late summer / early fall.

Coriolus forces increase as you get further from the equator.  Northern latitude storms should be tighter, smaller, with stronger winds.

While this is certainly too simple an analysis, is this on track as a first approximation:  Hurricanes 20 degrees further north, and possible at any time of the year?

Comment: Hurricanes my reach western Europe and New York. This is a terrible prospect.

Comment: This subject is not as simple as it sounds.  Since hurricanes are driven by heat, each time a hurricane forms, it sends a LOT of ocean heat high into the atmosphere at the eye of the hurricane, where that heat leaves earth via radiation heat transfer to outer space.  If the incidence of hurricanes goes up in the future, that will tend to decrease the expected temperature rise.

Comment: Interesting negative feedback loop.  My mental model was that a hurricane was just a way to disipate energy between the equatorial and polar regions, much like the hay stack waves in a river rapid. If hurricanes are heat transfer mechanisms between surface and space, they should show up as a hot spot in infra-red from the earth,yes?